# Heroku Build fail node_modules/.bin/sshpk-conv (File name too long)

Tags: angularjs, heroku, github, deployment, github-for-windows

Could anyone help me? I have activated continous integration on heroku with github, since yesterday when I make "git push heroku master", gives me the below error:

```
Counting objects: 721, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (593/593), done.
Writing objects: 100% (721/721), 1.54 MiB | 68.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 721 (delta 154), reused 499 (delta 78)
remote: error: unable to create symlink node_modules/.bin/sshpk-conv (File name too long)
remote:
remote: !       Heroku Git error, please try again shortly.
remote: !       See http://status.heroku.com for current Heroku platform status
remote: !       If the problem persists, please open a ticket
remote: !       on https://help.heroku.com/tickets/new
remote: !       and provide the Request ID X
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/weatheripca.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/weatheripca.git'
```

I already did the command: git config core.longpaths true, no success

Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already get this problem fixed. Activate longpath and made a force push.

```
git config --system core.longpaths true
```

Thank you